# How to show this inequality of probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_n,Y_n$ and $Z_n=X_n+Y_n$ be sequences of positive random variables such that $P(X_n<x)\geq a$ and $Y_n\to_p0$. Is it possible to show that

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}P(Z_n<x)\geq a?$$

My attempt:
$$P(Z_n<x) = P(X_n+Y_n<x-\epsilon+\epsilon,\;\forall \epsilon>0)\geq 1 - P(X_n\geq x-\epsilon,\;\forall\epsilon>0) - P(Y_n\geq \epsilon,\;\forall\epsilon>0),$$
where I use the fact that $P(X+Y<x+y)\geq 1 - P(X\geq x)-P(Y\geq y).$

Can I get rid of $\epsilon$ in the first probability? It looks that 
$$\left\{X_n\geq x-\epsilon,\;\forall\epsilon>0\right\} = \{X_n\geq x\}.$$

Then
$$P(Z_n<x)\geq a-P(Y_n\geq \epsilon,\;\forall\epsilon>0).$$

But I only know that $\forall\epsilon>0,\liminf_{n\to\infty}P(Y_n\geq \epsilon)=0$, while I have slightly different event inside probability.

On the other hand, if I split probabilities using $\forall\epsilon>0$
$$P(Z_n<x)\geq 1-P(X_n\geq x-\epsilon)-P(Y_n\geq \epsilon),$$
where the second probability disappears in the limit, but it is not clear what happens with the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $x = 1$, $X_n = 1 -1/n$, $Y_n = 1/n$.

Comment: Even worst, $x = 1$, $X_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n+1}$ and $Y_n = \frac{1}{n}$.